# Where is package linux-kernel-devel for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, make, dvb

Previously I rebuilt the 11.04 kernel to allow a TBS QBOX2 USB DVB satellite receiver to work, which it did very well under Kaffeine.

I now tried to build it on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with the following result:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-kernel-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-kernel-devel
```

Seems that the name has changed or Ubuntu isn't allowing this any more. Any idea of a solution please?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

That should download the the required files. YOu may need `build essential` packages also .